# Angular ReactiveForm with recursive template doesn't recognize parent formGroup directive

Tags: angular, angular-forms

In my app I construct `formGroups` dynamically from a config object that looks like this:

```
const formElements: FormElementInterface[] = [
 {
   type: 'formControl',
   defaultIsArray: false,
   defaultValue: 'Apfel',
   formControlName: 'fruits',
   htmlTag: 'mat-input',
   inputIype: 'text'
  } as InputFormControlInterface,
];
```

The `FormElementInterface[]` consists either of `formControl`objects  or `formGroup`objects. The latter can contain `formControls` or more `formGroups`.

Constructing the actual `formGroup`, which is called `completeForm` as you will see in the template, went smoothly, but inside the template I met some problem and got this error:

> formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class)

This is an excerpt from my template:

```
<form [formGroup]="completeForm">
 <div *ngFor="let formElement of forms">
  <ng-container
    *ngTemplateOutlet="formElement.type === 'formGroup' ? formGroup : formControl; context:{$implicit: formElement}">
  </ng-container>
 </div>
</form>

<ng-template #formControl let-formElement>
  <span [ngSwitch]="formElement.htmlTag">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'mat-input'">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput [value]="formElement.defaultValue" formControlName="fruits">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

As you can see `formGroup` is set. Are the `ng-template` interfering?

Comment: I think `*ngFor="let formElement of forms"` should be ` *ngFor="let formElement of formElements"`. And when the ngFor should be inside the form, not on the same tag. right?

Comment: I think it should be: `<span [formGroup]="formElement">`

Comment: @brandt.codes `*ngFor="let formElement of forms"` is ok, inside the component class I call `public forms = formElements;`.
Your second statement is indeed correct, but doesnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: due to the `ng-template` `formControlName` isnt sufficient since `ng-template` kinda messes up the hierarchy in the template. Therefore the path to the `formControl` inside the `formGroup` must be provided like so:

```
<input matInput [value]="formElement.defaultValue" [formControl]="getFormControl(formElement.formControlName)">
```